# Swift FBSDK Get user country

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, swift3, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I am currently implementing Facebook login for my app, and I am trying to fetch the following info from the profile:

first name,
last name,
gender,
and country.

However, I can only seem to fetch everything except the user country. I have tried to set my parameters to my FBSDKGraphRequest like this:

```
let parameters = ["fields": "email, gender, user_location, id, first_name, last_name,  picture.type(large)"]
```

as well as my readPermissions to:

```
loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_location", "user_friends", "user_education_history", "user_birthday"]
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I obtain the country of the user?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your readPermissions `user_location` is correct but the parameter name for country/location is not `user_location`.
 It is `location`.

```
let parameters = ["fields": "id,location,name,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large),email,birthday,gender,bio,relationship_status"]
```

Make sure you have added a **place** in your Facebook account and made that **public** in which your are logging in and you will be done. Try with the same facebook account from which you have created the facebook app.

You can get your location with a warning message(as shown screenshot later below) for testing purposes. But before submitting your app to appstore, you need to go through the Login Review from facebook as `user_location` is not a pre-Approved permission.

> **For More Details go to Graph API Explorer**

You can go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and try out with your app. Generate a token by clicking on **Get Token** and **Get User Access Token**. On clicking it will open the permission checkboxes. Keep **user_location** checked.

[image: Graph Api Explorer Page]

[image]

Next just click on Submit with the following **Get** Parameters. Make sure that the **location** parameter is there and you can see a JSON like this as shown.
There is a **location** dictionary with **name** key which consist of your country and city name.

```
{
  "id": "338058996547981",
  "name": "Rajan Maheshwari",
  "birthday": "04/29/1990",
  "location": {
    "id": "106517799384578",
    "name": "New Delhi, India"
  }
}
```

[image]

**NOTE: - Also you have to make sure that you have entered a place in your Facebook profile and made that public.**

[image]

When you will run the app with the permissions, you will get a Facebook authentication with a warning screen like this.

[image]

It will ask for a **Login Review** as some of the permissions need review here. The basic permissions provided free by facebook which don't need any review are:-

[image]

but for testing purposes you can get the location without any review. But before you will submit the iOS app to appstore, you need to pass the login review of Facebook in order to avoid that warning message and to fetch location of the user.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer Rajan. This is strange, it works in the Graph API Explorer, but not in my app (even though I changed it to 'location'. Hmm, anything more I have forgotten maybe?

Comment: @askaale in my app it's working, make sure your place is public and try login with same account from which you have created the app

Comment: I still can't seem to solve this problem. I noticed that my place was not public, but I changed this. However, it did not help. And also, would it be an easy way to only obtain the Country name of the user? Or would I have to obtain this by simply separating the string with a comma?

Comment: @askaale currently fb only provides location like this only

Comment: @askaale delete your app reset simulator and then install the application and get a new token, do login with same account from which you created the app

Comment: @askaale if this solves your problem, kindly accept as a tick. else do let me know in case of any problem

Comment: I got it to work, and I marked your response as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the country separately you can always use location{location}

```
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "location{location}"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            self.alertTheUser(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            print(error)
        }else{
            let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
            let location : NSDictionary! = fbDetails.value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary
            let locationContents : NSDictionary! = location.value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary
            self.registerCityField.text = locationContents.value(forKey: "city") as? String
            self.registerStateField.text = locationContents.value(forKey: "state") as? String
            self.registerCountryField.text = locationContents.value(forKey: "country") as? String
        }
    })
```